# coffeescript, class undefined variable.

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

I don't quite understand the syntax in coffeescript for defining an instance variable.

here's my scenario: I have an initializer and two classes, `Calculations` and `Controller`, Controller uses an instance of Calculations internally.

Here's the code:

initializer block

```
$ ->
  calc = new Calculations()
  log "initcalc: #{calc}"
  tc = new Controller(calc)
  tc.initForm()
```

where the log prints correctly: `initcalc: [object Object]`

the Class Calculations is defined as follows:

```
class Calculations
  constructor: ->
  updateFields: -> 
    log "updateFields"
```

the Class Controller is defined as:

```
class Controller
  constructor: (calc) ->
  initForm: -> 
    log "calc : #{@calc}"
    @calc.updateFields()
```

the init form is called by the initializer right after instantiating the classes here's it's output:

```
calc : undefined trade_class_new.js?body=1:8
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'updateFields' of undefined
```

I don't understand how's the syntax for an instance variable in coffeescript.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `Controller` constructor to:

```
constructor: (@calc) ->
```

Otherwise it's just taking a `calc` parameter and doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

The controller constructor needs to be (@calc) instead of (calc)